# I can't get route53 to redirect to my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

So I have an EC2 instance on AWS, associated it with an elastic IP; bought a domain (abstron.net) from Amazon, and tried to use route53 to route abstron.net to EC2.

I created a hosted zone, put in the domain name as abstron.net, created a new record, put the elastic IP (also tried public IP) without a name, but when I try to access abstron.net, it times out or does not load.

I am running a server on port 80 on EC2; the direct URL used for SSH works just fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a web server running on your EC2 instance?  And how are you trying to access the domain?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do have a web server instance running on EC2; it is serving on port 80.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein for some reason, even the original link stopped working; the IP currently does not work. I'm gonna try restarting the instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think it might be related to cloudflare actually

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to update the name servers of your Route 53 hosted zone with your domain registrar (abstron.net). Please update the same and try to access the website. This should work.

Thanks!